# PHP require_once throws error locally in Mac OSX Lion

Tags: php, macos, osx-lion, require-once

I am trying to use a relative path locally on a Mac OSX lion using `require_once`:

```
require_once('../../folder/file.php5');
```

And it throws an error every time:

```
PHP Warning: require_once(../../folder/file.php5): failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in - on line 6 PHP Fatal error: require_once(): 
Failed opening required '../../folder/file.php5' (include_path='.:') in - on line 6
```

The file and folder structure is exactly the same as the Web host and it works there with out issue.

```
require_once('../../folder/file.php5');
```

The other odd thing is I can only get the PHP error via previewing via my code editor CODA. If I load the same URL in my browser, it outputs the body of the PHP5 file as you would see it in plain text.

What causes the above Failure?

Answer (score 0):

The error output says that your `include_path` is `.:`. I doubt it's the problem, but have you tried setting it to just `.`? Or putting another path after the colon? (etc, `.:/some/other/path`)

Comment: I did try that, I never got it work. Installed MAMP and it worked.